# Selecting a custom icon to use with the Trillan chat client

Tags: trillian

I'd like to replace the icon that Trillian uses to represent me with a custom one, but the option to select a custom file for the icon doesn't appear in the "change icon" menu.

How do I go about replacing the icon with a custom one?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might just need to add the picture you want to the directory that the other icons are stored in.

Comment: What version of Trillian are you using? I see the option "Load a photo" in Trillian 5.1 avatar settings. Also just confirming you are talking about your display avatar right? And not the Trillian application logo?

Comment: @Dracs gah! I didn't look at the labels on the buttons - I assumed the option was just a funny looking icon. Thanks! Post that as the answer please :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the desired image to .ico format with an image editing program. [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.ca/) works for this purpose.


EDIT: To change your display picture, go to Preferences, then Accounts, click the top one, and you should see "Disconnect All" and "Set Icon...". Click Set Icon and then "Load a photo..." to use your own image

[image: Trillian Set Icon]

Comment: Are you sure? Most other chat programs let me use any image as the source for my icon.

Comment: Oh... you mean display picture? I totally thought you meant the icon on the shortcut -.(\

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it from the web, however, if you’re using a Mac, you can.

Check in the **preferences** where your identity is, or click on your picture (or lack of) on the contact list.

From the contact list:

1. Click the **accounts** rectangle at the top, opening the Accounts window.
2. Click on the non-existent avatar, producing a drop-down selection.
3. Select **Edit Avatar**...

I've assumed your using a MAC. Is this a valid assumption?

Comment: No, I'm using a PC and an iPhone. Changing it on either client would work.

Answer (score 1):

To change your current avatar image. Open up Trillian's preferences and go to the account page. If you select your identity (should be the top one), the option for "Set Icon" should appear. From there select the option "Load a photo...". That will allow you to choose your own avatar image from your computer.